# how do i get css source file path from firebug?

Tags: css, file, firebug

I need to modify a couple of classes in the css of the site i'm currently woking on. another person worked in it, so i really don't know where he has put the styles. i know firebug shows the css path on the corner, but it's just showing the url like this: http://localseo.org#3(line 149) . what does it mean? how do I get the file path? Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, that'd be inline style block #3 at line 149 of the page you're on. If it was an external .css file, it'd show which one as part of that url.

Comment: That's not normal... can you provide a screenshot of the CSS panel?

Comment: @Snowbell92 Press the 'checkmark' next to the answer that solves your answer or problem.

Comment: Look at the source of the generated page in your browser. it'd be embedded in there. that'd give you an idea of what to look for in the theme files.

Comment: thanks mark. apparently, the previous coder added styles in custom fields!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on that URL.
It will open the correct file to the correct line.  From there you can easily see the path...

[image: CSS file exploring in Firebug]

**However,** if you mean ***file*** path, on the server, you cannot get that from the browser or Firebug; it depends on your server settings.

Answer (score 2):

Open firebug and you'll see a **CSS** pane/tab you can then select the stylesheet you want/need to edit.