# Where is style coming if Firebug does not show the source file?

Tags: css, firebug

I know how to use Firebug to find and view the css files that set css on a page. For instance, this post shows what to do if Firebug tells you where css is coming from:
[how do i get css source file path from firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128369/how-do-i-get-css-source-file-path-from-firebug)

But sometimes firebug does not show the source css file. Why is that? If firebug does not show a source css file, then where is the css coming from?

[image]

Comment: Usually means that the styles are applied to the element via the "style" attribute (right within the tag).

Comment: These are inline, which means they were hard coded inline or added dynamically with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`element.style` are inline styles for that element. What you have in your picture would be something like this:

```
<a style = "display:block; height:auto; left:176px; top:71px; width:920px"></a>
```

jQuery functions that modify the visual part of an element such as `.css()`, `.fadeIn()`, `.offset()` also apply css this way.

Answer (score 0):

It may used by the *inline* style or Javascript or jquery plugins may also added inline style dynamically.